# What are some realistic defenses against laser weapons in space?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, weapons, lasers

In a mostly-realistic sci-fi setting (similar to the Expanse) there are spaceships, satellites, and drones who make use of high-powered lasers for weaponry - both for attack and for point defense.

What are some realistic ways to defend against lasers? No Star Trek shields - unless there are some good theories on how they might actually work.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me somebody will inevitably say "mirrors" and we'll all have to debunk that myth yet again.  Anyway, this question has been asked before, e.g.: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/115532/how-to-protect-your-ship-against-tw-range-lasers

Comment: Bleugh, the answers to the linked question regurgitate all the same old mistakes that @GrumpyYoungMan was concerned about, plus some more... mirrors and sandcasters. I guess its a small mercy that someone hasn't brought up the old "thermal superconductor" canard, too...

Comment: Mirror is actually half right, or can I say 99.999% correct, that 0.001% could prove fatal because small amount of absorption builds up quickly and dangerously ;D

Comment: @user6760 by "quickly", you presumably mean "in a microsecond", or possibly even "it was shiny when we left orbit, but micrometeor and solar wind damage have taken a bit of a toll over the last few weeks".